# Apache2 ProxyPass to Tomcat, DirectoryIndex with exclusions

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, directoryindex

We're deploying a SpringMVC application and using an Apache frontend to make
it easier to for our less technically inclined employees to upload images in
to the application without having to redeploy the application and such
annoyances; it also handles our SSL so that our SSL deployment can be easily
standardized.

To that end, we're using an Apache2 frontend sitting on :443 which handles
SSL, and splicing in data from our CMS to this end:

```
ProxyPass /client-ui/images/rich/ !
Alias /client-ui/images/rich/ /var/lib/cms/images/
```

as well as something like

```
<Location /client-ui/>
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/client-ui/ timeout=3600
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/client-ui/
</Location>
```

One thing which our deployment hasn't managed to take care of yet is that the
application lives on `/client-ui/betptc/home` so when someone visits the site
they have to hit `example.com/client-ui/betptc/home`. I'd like to set up a
DirectoryIndex on `/` that simply redirects to the main application.

However, if I do a bang'd ProxyPass like I do with the images directory, the
entire domain gets kept from proxying to Tomcat; the `/client-ui/` block isn't
recognized or respected.

Is there any other way to do that? I don't know our Spring application very
well, so I'm hesitant to explore adding the redirect on that end, but if
there's a way to do it there I'm open to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just..

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ http://example.com//client-ui/betptc/home
```

But exempting the proxy will work too.

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/$ !
```

(that would need to go above your existing `ProxyPass` lines, since they're processed in order)